# Tinting an image in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm looking on how to tint an image in Pygame in a similar fashion of how Monogame does it. I've been trying to get custom flags like BLEND_ADD to work but it's been hard to find concise examples of what I'm looking for, it's mostly been people trying to "darken" or work with the alpha levels in a way.

Question:
How do I tint an image to a certain RGBA value in the same way that MonoGame does it?

Comment: I'm not sure such kind of open question is good for Stack Overflow. Adding an image so we can see what this "Monogame " does, may possibly help.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't think that'd be something I need to explain. Monogame is a library in C# for creating games. Similar to how Pygame is a module  in Python. At least that's how I understand things. I don't consider this an open question in that regard since it has a spritebatch.draw method which handles drawing things, it has a parameter that passes through an Color which it tints to(default is (0, 0, 0) which means it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is it an open source library?

Comment: Yes, you can see at https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/SpriteBatch.cs
If you look at the method on line 591. I don't actually understand what's going on there with the Color or what it does with it to tint, that's what I'm asking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fill your image with a color and pass one of the [`BLEND`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) constants as the `special_flags` argument, e.g. `your_image.fill((190, 0, 0, 100), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_ADD)`.

Note that `BLEND_RGB_ADD` is just an alias for `BLEND_ADD` (and the same applies to the other modes). The `RGBA` modes will also modify the alpha channel (ADD and MAX make transparent parts visible).

Here's a table that shows you the effects of the different blending modes (I've also added the names of the modes in Photoshop):

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, although this doesn't give the exact same behavior as in Monogame this helped me solve my problem. Thank you,